# I need to use getline() every time the function is called. How to avoid repeating reading the same lines in txt? c++

Tags: c++, fstream, getline

I need to make a function that every time I click the button, the program read and act according to a line in the log_p.txt file.

However, if I put the read t process inside the function, every time it will read the first line.

```
void ai_fight::getfile()
{
    std::ifstream t("log_p.txt");

    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);

    getline(t, rule);

    print_rule(rule);

    if(getline(t, p1hand)) print_p1hand(p1hand);

    if(getline(t, p1p)) print_p1p(p1p);

    if(getline(t, p2hand)) print_p2hand(p2hand);

    if(getline(t, p2p)) print_p2p(p2p);

    getline(t, announce);
    if(announce=="1 eliminated"||announce=="0 eliminated")
    {
        getline(t, buf);
        getline(t, buf);
        getline(t, buf);
        getline(t, buf);
        getline(t, win);
        print_win(win);
        ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
     }
     else if(announce=="0 winning"||announce=="1 winning")
     {
        ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
     }
     else qDebug()<<"----------announcement error"<<endl;
    ui->pushButton->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: "However, if I put the read t process inside the function, every time it will read the first line." I don't really get what you mean by that. The nature of `std::ifstream` after opening a file is to start reading from the first character in the file. Is it that you do *not* intend to do so?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just read the entire file into memory? Something like a vector of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to store the `ifstream` as a class member.

```
void ai_fight::getfile()
{
    if (!m_t.is_open())
         m_t.open("log_p.txt");
    ...
```

You probably want to close the file when you reach EOF so that you can loop round.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you open a file it will start reading it from the beginning. What you need is to remember the current position in file persistently between function calls. You can achieve it in (at least) two ways:

1. Open the file outside of the function (e.g. as a class member). This way the file will be opened during the whole execution and the ifstream object will remember the current position.
2. Store the current position in the file in some variable. You can use `tellg` and `seekg` methods to get and set the cursor position in file stream. Of course you need to store this value outside the function.